# How to append data to shapefile?

Tags: python, pyshp

I have a shapefile. and some data there. 
It's the way I created it:

```
w = shapefile.Writer('shapefiles/test/line_2')
w.field('Latitude','C')
w.poly(arr)
w.record('linestring3')
w.close()
```

Now, I want to append data to this shapefile. 
How it can be done?

Thanks